# Retrieve the value of a field with an unknown type from a JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

**Java / `class JSONObject`:**

I have a `JSONObject` instance as input.

The structure of the JSON is constant, except for one field, whose type is either one of the following:

- `Integer`
- `Long`
- `String` (containing decimal-digit characters only)

What is the best way to extract the value of this field into a `String`, without `try/catch` each type?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the value `v` of this field as `Object`. Then do `v + ""` or `v.toString()`, and there is your string.

Comment: Just use `get` - How could I have missed that??? (thought it was returning a `JSONObject` for some reason). Thanks, man!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.valueOf(object);`

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28boolean%29).